# how can i throttle an array into a stream created using rxjs "from" operator?

Tags: arrays, rxjs, throttling

I want to throttle the contents of an array observable created with "from" operator to display each value 1 second apart. Omitting the throttle displays 1 to 10 as expected. If I introduce a throttle into the observable's pipe() the stream only outputs "1".

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-knappa?file=index.ts

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { throttle } from 'rxjs/operators';

const observable = from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
const example = observable.pipe(
  // removing this line displays the full array all at once
  throttle(ev => interval(1000))
  // what we want is 1..2..3..4.. printed in succession, 1 number a second
);
example.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

How can i print the numbers of the array 1 second apart?

By extension how can i add numbers to the stream created using "from" and continue to throttle those values 1 second apart?

This is quite unintuitive. Any help will be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need throttle, it is a little different thing in RxJS. Have a look at this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57097217/8578281

Answer (score 2):

I had to google but this should give you what you want:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const observable = from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
const example = observable.pipe(
  // removing this line displays the full array all at once
  concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(1000)))
  // what we want is 1..2..3..4.. printed in succession, 1 number a second
);
example.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-delay-from-array

Comment: thanks your answer achieves end result but doesn't demonstate how throttle is used to slow down emission of an array or other value source. i need to understand why throttle doesnt work as its an intermediate step on understanding how to throttle values from other events.

Comment: Ok, I will try with `throttle` later

Comment: hey thanks that wasnt a request but im really grateful for your help and insight.

Comment: No problem,  I don't think `throttle` is what you want because `throttle` ignores observables that emit within that timeframe. I tried fiddling with it, I wasn't able to do it.