# Equivalent to debounce operator Rx

Tags: android, rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2

Actually I need to implement something like `debounce` operator, but let's take an example. If I set debounce for 5 sec, so user can click on button 10 time within 5 sec and just after 5 sec expire the last click event will be taken to account.

What I need is option when 5 sec set as a time range and when user click 10 times just first click will be taken to account **immediately** and all other clicks that were emitted within 5 sec time range will be dismissed.

After 5 sec user can start clicking again.

How to do it?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059666/how-does-throttletime-operators-config-parameter-work-throttleconfig

Answer (score 2):

There is another operator in RxJS to accomplish your task, `throttleTime`.

It will subscribe to the first value emitted and then wait for 5second and then again emit value after 5 second.

```
const source = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  throttleTime(5000),
);
```

Please find working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hwviuc

You can study more on [throttleTime here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime)

Comment: In RxJava the operator is called `throttleLatest(...)`